# Encrypt in Javascript and Decrypt in Java For Zip File

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, encoding, zip

I want to encrypt local zip file in javascript, then decrypt it in java.

I used code from this link https://www.devglan.com/corejava/aes-encryption-javascript-and-decryption-in-java

encrypt in javascript

```
var AesUtil = function (keySize, iterationCount) {
    this.keySize = keySize / 32;
    this.iterationCount = iterationCount;
};

AesUtil.prototype.generateKey = function (salt, passPhrase) {
    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(
        passPhrase,
        CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(salt),
        {keySize: this.keySize, iterations: this.iterationCount});
    return key;
};

AesUtil.prototype.encrypt = function (salt, iv, passPhrase, plainText) {
    var key = this.generateKey(salt, passPhrase);
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        plainText,
        key,
        {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv)});
    return encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
};

AesUtil.prototype.decrypt = function (salt, iv, passPhrase, cipherText) {
    var key = this.generateKey(salt, passPhrase);
    var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(cipherText)
    });
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        cipherParams,
        key,
        {iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv)});
    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);


};

var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js'),
    fs = require('fs');

var data = fs.readFileSync("C:\\<my_path>\\scripts.zip");

var passPhrase = "123456789123456789";
var iv = "a145525c53eafb0258999612b13d9d3e"; //CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
var salt = "ca70e17a698096cfb42047926713dd62";// CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);

var aesUtil = new AesUtil(128, 1000);
var ciphertext = aesUtil.encrypt(salt, iv, passPhrase, data.toString());

fs.writeFileSync('C:/Output.encrypted', ciphertext);
```

and decryption in java is like this:
***AesUtil.java***

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

public class AesUtil {
    private final int keySize;
    private final int iterationCount;
    private final Cipher cipher;

    public AesUtil(int keySize, int iterationCount) {
        this.keySize = keySize;
        this.iterationCount = iterationCount;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw fail(e);
        }
    }

    public String decrypt(String salt, String iv, String passphrase, String ciphertext) {
        try {
            SecretKey key = generateKey(salt, passphrase);
            byte[] decrypted = doFinal(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv, base64(ciphertext));
            return new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return null;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public byte[] doFinal(int encryptMode, SecretKey key, String iv, byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            cipher.init(encryptMode, key, new IvParameterSpec(hex(iv)));
            return cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException
                | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException
                | BadPaddingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public SecretKey generateKey(String salt, String passphrase) {
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), hex(salt), iterationCount, keySize);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
            return key;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] base64(String str) {
        return Base64.decodeBase64(str);
    }

    public static byte[] hex(String str) {
        try {
            return Hex.decodeHex(str.toCharArray());
        }
        catch (DecoderException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private IllegalStateException fail(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Main method:

```
private static void mainScan(String[] args) {
        try {
            String keyString = "123456789123456789";


            int keySize = 128;
            int iterationCount = 1000;
            String iv = "a145525c53eafb0258999612b13d9d3e";
            String salt = "ca70e17a698096cfb42047926713dd62";
            AesUtil aesUtil = new AesUtil(keySize, iterationCount);


            String encryptedPath = "C:/Output.encrypted";
            String decryptedPath = "C:/Output.zip";


            String fileString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(encryptedPath)));
            String decryptedText = aesUtil.decrypt(salt, iv, keyString, fileString);

            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(decryptedPath), decryptedText);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But still, after decryption, I got a zip file that is bigger size from the original zip and isn't a valid zip file.

- Note: This code worked when the text was only String and not getting the string from/to file

Comment: If you're using the same salt and IV strings, they look hex-encoded, not Base64.

Comment: The problem here is in two places. In the javascript, it is in `var ciphertext = aesUtil.encrypt(salt, iv, passPhrase, data.toString());`. `data.toString()` is wrong. And in the Java, at the end of decrypt, you return `new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");`. In both cases you are treating the plaintext, a zip file, as a String. It is a sequence of arbitrary bytes, not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treating binary content like Zip files as if they were strings is usually a big mistake in most languages. On the Javascript side, CryptoJS expects arbitrary bytes sequences to be supplied as `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray` arguments.

So, instead of

```js
var ciphertext = aesUtil.encrypt(salt, iv, passPhrase, data.toString());
```

you should have

```js
var ciphertext = aesUtil.encrypt(salt, iv, passPhrase, CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(data));
```

On the Java side, change the function decrypt to return a `byte[]`.

```java
public byte[] decrypt(String salt, String iv, String passphrase, String ciphertext) {
    SecretKey key = generateKey(salt, passphrase);
    byte[] decrypted = doFinal(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv, base64(ciphertext));
    return decrypted;
}
```

And in `main`, change the code to look something like

```
String fileString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(encryptedPath)));
byte [] decryptedText = aesUtil.decrypt(salt, iv, keyString, fileString);
Files.write(Paths.get(decryptedPath), decryptedText);
```